# Removing x-amount of letters in a string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string

So in the database I have the following value:

"H-000000107"

I need to remove everything in the string in vb.net except the 107 at the end, the issue is, sometimes the last value can be longer eg.

"H-000001207"

In this case I need to return 1207 from the string. So the amount of letters and characters in front of the actual code (1207) is not always the same. Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: tried out my answer.?

Comment: it sounds that simple answer is more then long one ...

Comment: what about my answer ? it works i have tested it

Comment: I would use the right function, only select what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the work on all propabilities of after the  `H-`

```
dim a as string = "H-000000107"
dim b as string = "H-000001207"

dim newval = -int(a.ToString.Split("H")(1)).tostring 'output 107

dim newval2  = -int(b.ToString.Split("H")(1)).tostring 'output 1207
```

Comment: PLEASE CONSID ADDING A COMMENT WHENE VOTING DOWN

Comment: Hi thanks K3rnel31, I tested yours as well and it also works perfect in each scenario. And true this way is shorter :)

Comment: Have no idea who is down voting everything

Comment: @JohnathanSalmon yeah i see so can u turn it at correct answer

Comment: why are you converting a string into string.? `.ToString()`. Why don't you use `Math.Abs()`?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy if you need to use the result as string so must be converted to string if you need it as integer let it without .tostring math.abs it is a solution too

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy whene u use `Math.abs()` the result is in `Double` so we must convert it to string too

Comment: You declared `a` and `b` as a string.? Is there any peculiar reason to convert it into string again.? `-int(a.ToString..`

Comment: yeah but after that `int(string)` ==> `integer`

Comment: well It seems like an unproductive discussion. Your code is perfectly alright. carry on.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the best idea is the first one check the last edit because Math.abs accept negatif number so is long way

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ok after that dont forget to turn it as coorect answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Dim xString = "H-000001207"
Dim xResult = string.empty

for i as integer = 0 to xString.length -1

  if (xString.chars(i) = "H" orelse _
      xString.chars(i) = "-" orelse _
     (xString.chars(i) = "0" andalso not xResult = string.empty)) then

    continue for

  else

    xResult &= xString.chars(i)

  end if

next 

MsgBox(val(xResult))
```

or May be a simple solution like this,

```
Dim xString = "H-000001207"
dim xRes = String.Empty 

if xString.length > 3 then
   xRes = val(xString.substring(2, xString.length-2))
end if
```

Comment: Hi, yes I tried the answer but it returns H17 as the result for the string, I am going through it now to see whats going on

Comment: @JohnathanSalmon I don't have an IDE here. :) try out the second one.

Comment: So far the second option is returning the results I'm looking for, well done without the IDE. Just need to test it with different scenarios before marking it as answered but thanks!

Comment: @JohnathanSalmon Well its your matter of choice :). By the way I just updated the first one. I hope that, it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (note that the result will be an empty string if you pass words like "H-"):

```
string result="";
           string words = "H-000001207";

           string[] split = words.Split(new Char[] { '-'});

           if (split.GetUpperBound(0) == 1)
           {
               result = split[1].TrimStart('0');

           }
           else
               result = "Error-Invalid format.";

           Console.WriteLine(result);//is 1207
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with Regex:

```
Dim pattern = "[1-9]\d*$"
Dim input = "H-000001207"
Dim result = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
Console.WriteLine(result.Value) '1207
```

Pattern explanation: Return the value at the end of the string ($) which starts by a digit other than zero ([1-9]) and is followed by 0 or more digits (\d*).